# Cloning a project from git returns the project though modules show as directories

Tags: git, intellij-idea, module, directory, cloning

Pre-problem: the usual apology if this question has been settled.

Problem:

I have cloned a project from a a shared repository on bitbucket to my IntelliJ-IDE. The issue is that only the root folder shows as a module while all sub-modules show as sub-directories(without the little blue square to indicate module-type in the project-view). Surely, the sub-modules are sub-directories, but I need them to work as actual modules.

[see how there are no blue squares on the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzKDU.jpg)

[It should be achievable, like this, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHBtX.jpg)

It seems like all I can do is clone it seperately, then import from existing source, but this causes two other issues:

1. The root folder is not included as the root of the project, though I'm not sure this is a major issue.
2. When pulling, new modules pushed to the repository since last pull is included in the actual pull but won't show up in the project-tree, while when trying to import it seperately "from existing module" causes intelliJ to inform that it already exists(even though it isn't visible) and prompts me to rename the imported module and create a copy.

It all seems very cumbersome to duplicate and work from a new path, and while I'm sure there's a fix, I'm wondering if there's any common procedure or practice to make intelliJ behave nice and lean with project consistency across all collaborator-instances.

All attempted search queries here and on google seem to return irrelevant or misleading results.
Hopefully some of you out there will be able to assist, and any additional information will gladly be provided upon request :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider one of the following:

- [Keep IDE projects files in the version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) so that all the modules and the project can be configured once and reused by other developers
- Use Maven or Gradle for the project, this way IntelliJ IDEA will import the project and configure all the modules and their dependencies automatically

Otherwise, you will have to configure all the modules, libraries and dependencies manually on every machine you have cloned this project to (New empty project, then add modules one by one in the Project Structure, configure Source and Test roots, if automatic import from the existing sources produces wrong results).